# Extra Vertical Lines in the Column Heading Names

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, primefaces

[image]I have one datatable in primefaces and has 9 columns.In some of the columns like in 3rd,4th column displaying the extra vertical lines and in rest of columns its not displaying any extra vertical line.

```
<p:dataTable id="accCertificateList" var="cert"
                        styleClass="mySubPanelStyle"

        value="#{certificateSearchHandler.certificateInfoList}"
                        paginator="true" rows="#  {label.accountList_defaultNumberOfRows}"
                        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}   {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                        rowsPerPageTemplate="#{label.accountList_numberOfRows}">
                        <p:column style="width:5%;vertical-align: top;" >
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputLabel value="Select" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cert.change}">
                                <f:ajax event="click"
                                    render=":certificateList:certificateListCertGrid"
                                    listener="#{certificateSearchHandler.selectCertList}"
                                    update=":certificateList:certificateListCertGrid">
                                </f:ajax>
                                <f:attribute name="selectCert" value="#{cert}" />
                            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="text-align:center;white-space: normal;width:8%; vertical-align: top;" 
                            filterBy="#{cert.certificateNumber}" filterStyle ="width:35px"
                            sortBy="#{cert.certificateNumber}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{label.certNo}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:graphicImage id="lock" rendered="#{cert.certificateLock}"
                                        style="width:25%" url="/images/icons/I_Lock.png">
                                        <p:tooltip targetPosition="bottomLeft" Delay="0"
                                            showDelay="0">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{label.lockTime}"
                                                style="font-weight:bold" />
                                            <h:outputText value=": #{cert.lockTime}" />
                                            <p:spacer width="1" height="10" />
                                            <h:outputText value="#{cert.label} " style="font-weight:bold" />
                                            <h:outputText value=": #{cert.userDetails}" />

                                        </p:tooltip>

                                    </h:graphicImage>
                            <h:outputText value="#{cert.certificateNumber}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="text-align:center;white-space: normal;nowrap;width:15%; vertical-align: top;"
                            filterBy="#{cert.certificateHolder.additionalInterest.generalPartyInfo.nameInfo.commlName.commercialName}"
                            sortBy="#{cert.certificateHolder.additionalInterest.generalPartyInfo.nameInfo.commlName.commercialName}"
                            filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{label.certHolder}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{cert.certificateHolder.additionalInterest.generalPartyInfo.nameInfo.commlName.commercialName}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="text-align:center;white-space: normal;nowrap;width:25%; vertical-align: top;" 
                            filterBy="#{cert.holderaddress}" 
                            sortBy="#{cert.holderaddress}"
                            filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{label.certHolderAddr}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{cert.holderaddress}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="text-align:center;white-space: normal;nowrap;width:15%; vertical-align: top;" 
                            filterBy="#{cert.insureds}" sortBy="#{cert.insureds}"
                            filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{label.insured}" />
                            </f:facet>

                            <h:outputText value="#{cert.insureds}" />

                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="text-align:center;white-space: normal;width:9%; vertical-align: top;" 
                            filterBy="#{cert.statusOnScreen}" filterStyle ="width:55px"
                            sortBy="#{cert.statusOnScreen}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{label.certStatus}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{cert.statusOnScreen}"
                                title="#{cert.statusOnScreen}" />
                        </p:column>



                        <p:column style="text-align:center;white-space: normal;width:10%; vertical-align: top;" 
                            filterBy="#{cert.certificateIssuedDt}"   filterStyle ="width:60px"
                            sortBy="#{cert.certificateIssuedDt}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{label.issueDt}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{cert.certificateIssuedDt}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="text-align:center;white-space:normal;width:5%;vertical-align: top;" >
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{label.thirdParty}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{cert.com_csc_EndorsementTPInd}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="text-align:center;width:6%;vertical-align: top;">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputLabel value="#{label.certAction}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <ui:repeat
                                value="#{cert.availableFunctions.functionArrayCertList}"
                                var="linkInfo">
                                <h:commandLink id="View" value="#{linkInfo.label}"
                                    action="#{linkInfo.getLabel}" ajax="false"
                                    disabled="#{linkInfo.disable}">
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{cert}"  name="selectCert"
                                        target="#{certificateSearchHandler.selectedCertificate}" />
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="Link"  name="selectCert"
                                        target="#{certificateSearchHandler.selection}" />
                                </h:commandLink>
                                <p:spacer width="5" height="2" />
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: There is just too many things going in your code to say for sure.  If you remove the inline style attribute from the column, does the vertical bar go away?  Try opening the page in Firefox and use the Firebug add-on to remove CSS from the table header until the bar goes away.  It probably has something to do with the use of `nowrap` and percentage widths.

Comment: Your problem is likely some styling issue, which your code does not help resolve. If you could supply the actual output html of the table header area and any relevant css (or a link to a live example), then someone might be able to help you. NOTE: it appears to me that it may be an additional table cell in the header that happens to have its right border property set but shouldn't.